# Custom route not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

In my routes.rb file, I have:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :tickets, except: [:edit] do
    member do
      put 'save_and_close', to: 'tickets#save_and_close'
    end
  end   
end
```

In my controllers/admin/tickets_controller.rb, I have:

```
def save_and_close
  success_message = I18n.t('notices.ticket_successfully_updated')
  @ticket = Ticket.find params[:id]
  @ticket.assign_attributes(params[:ticket])
  if @ticket.save
    redirect_to admin_tickets_path, notice: success_message
  else
    flash.now[:error] = @ticket.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
    render action: "show"
  end
end
```

In my views/admin/tickets/show.html.slim, I have:

```
= link_to 'Save & Close', save_and_close_admin_ticket_path, class: 'btn btn-success ticket-event btn-lg'
```

From rake route, I have:

```
save_and_close_admin_ticket PUT  /admin/tickets/:id/save_and_close(.:format)  admin/tickets#save_and_close
```

But, when I click on the Save & Close button, I get the following error message:

```
Started GET "/admin/tickets/163925/save_and_close" for 73.83.66.151 at 2017-03-02 05:26:22 +0000
Processing by ApplicationController#routing_error as HTML
Parameters: {"unmatched_route"=>"admin/tickets/163925/save_and_close"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 28.2ms
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches admin/tickets/163925/save_and_close):
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
= link_to 'Save & Close', save_and_close_admin_ticket_path(@ticket), method: :put, class: 'btn btn-success ticket-event btn-lg'
```

Comment: It should be @ticket, not ticket (passed to path), but yes, I forgot to specify a method, otherwise it works

Comment: Copy of previous person answer.

Comment: @Nickey what do you mean by copy of previous answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have method type `PUT` in routes and calling route with `GET`. also no ticket id supplied in path.

`link_to` by default process with `GET` request, So you need to specify method type in link to manually. do this:

```
= link_to 'Save & Close', save_and_close_admin_ticket_path(ticket), method: :put, class: 'btn btn-success ticket-event btn-lg'
```

Comment: This should be a comment.